# Make a bash function fail when on empty

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a function that always have a non empty output or fails, but I'm missing a command that read stdin and pipe it to stdout if non-empty or fails like:

```bash
example() {
  do_something_interesting_here $1 | cat_or_fails
}
```

The idea is that if the command `cat_or_fails` is given an empty input it fails (so the function fails) or the input is output without any changes (like `cat`).

But I could not find any standard utility capable of that trick, or may be I'm not sure how to use those tools.

Comment: This smells like something that would be in [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), but software recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: ...so if I were to treat this as on-topic, I'd answer for how I'd implement this in bash _without_ discussing 3rd-party tools for the same purpose.

Comment: I'm thinking on something as a clever trick for a standard tool, like for example using `grep` with something that matches anything non-empty for example... it simply feels like there is an common solution that I'm not seeing...

Comment: Maybe `grep .` does what you're looking for.  This returns non-zero if the input is purely whitespace, so maybe not what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd use an awk one-liner if you care about terseness (which I could argue at length that you shouldn't -- terseness in shell is often achieved at the expense of correctness), but no, there's no "common solution".

Comment: `grep .` also deletes blank lines, so maybe `grep '^\|.'`

Comment: ...the examples using `grep` with side effects arguably prove my point re: the terseness-vs-correctness tradeoff. "Simpler" in terms of ease-of-reading does not necessarily mean "simpler" in terms of simplicity of operation; better to have more lines with less ambiguous behavior than fewer lines that, in corner cases, do things you don't intend behind your back.

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm to accomplish this is trivial and obvious: Try to read one byte. If it works, write that byte back out and then run `cat`. If it fails, exit with a nonzero status.

Both below variants can be used in the manner described in the question (`... | cat_or_fails`).

---

A very simple implementation (that doesn't try to handle binary files starting with the NUL character) would look like:

```
cat_or_fails() {
  local firstbyte
  IFS= read -r -n 1 firstbyte || return
  printf '%s' "${firstbyte:-$'\n'}"
  cat
}
```

---

A slightly less simple implementation that *does* try to handle binary files correctly might look like:

```
cat_or_fails() {
  local firstbyte
  IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 firstbyte || return
  if [[ $firstbyte ]]; then
    printf '%s' "$firstbyte"
  else
    printf '\0'
  fi
  cat
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `test -s /dev/stdin` as an alternative to `read` and then cat all of the output if true. Seems to work on bash on macos 12 anyway.

Comment: @kojiro, ...it _does_ seem to work (on MacOS 12, as you say); but without knowing how it works and whether those semantics are portable I'm hesitant to trust it. If it's relying on `stat` data, that's very OS-dependent.

Comment: Sometimes I wish there were a service that could test stupid bash tricks on a bunch of OSs at once. There used to be this great one called Twitter. Oh well!

Comment: @kojiro, actually, I'm not so sure that works reliably at all. `{ sleep 3; echo hi; } | test -s /dev/stdin` -- you'll see it's false. Smells like we're just testing if the pipe buffer is empty when `test` finishes forking off and starting up.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't actually _read_ from stdin. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of [@William Pursell in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522490/make-a-bash-function-fail-when-on-empty#comment131550193_74522490) it seems that grep can do the trick using something like:

```bash
example() {
  do_something_interesting_here $1 | grep "[[:alnum:]]"
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, it will consume any empty lines (or any line that don't match the regex given).

Comment: ...really? You want to treat a line with, say, `===` (or other non-alphanumeric content) as if it didn't exist at all? William's original comment has far less serious side effects than this purportedly-based-on-it answer.

Comment: Beyond that, what if the thing you're trying to create is a tarball, or a cpio archive, or any other non-textual content? Having constraints on what content it can process correctly makes this a very special-purpose tool; it might work for your _immediate_ purpose, but it's not something people can keep in their toolbelt and use whenever they like.

Answer (score 1):

My usual trick to assure that at least one line of a text file is found follows. It is all standard shell stuff... bash, ksh, zsh.

```
example() {
  set -o pipefail     #assure failure on do_something is not suppressed
  do_something_interesting_here $1 | 
       grep .           #assure no output returns error
}
```

If you need pipefail to cancel when the function returns:

```
example() {
 (   #isolate pipefail in subshell
  set -o pipefail     #assure failure on do_something is not suppressed
  do_something_interesting_here $1 | 
       grep .           #assure no output returns error
 )
}
```

Comment: If it were `grep '.\|^$'` you'd avoid stripping empty lines while still failing on zero-byte output. (One-byte output with only a newline would result in success, but a newline is not _empty_, so that smells like success).

Comment: Mind, try `printf abc | grep .` -- you'll see that because there's no trailing newline it's nonzero. In some circumstances that might be okay, but it's still not quite a general-purpose tool for detecting zero-byte input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I'm aware of  those edge cases. But as I said this is my "usual trick" and it works for the vast majority of the cases. And if the last line is formatted in one of those odd ways it usually indicates a bug somewhere.

Comment: Or an input file that was never meant to be text in the first place, or DOS/Windows files, etc. Anyhow -- I meant to suggest a minor amendment (changing `grep .` to even just `grep ^`), not to criticize on its own. No reason not to change your usual trick if it can be improved. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `grep '.\|^$'` feels wrong; POSIX basic regexps don't support `\|` and extended ones will fail because of the backslash

Comment: @Fravadona, how about `grep ^`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That should work with any `grep` implementation (I tested it on AIX/Solaris/Linux/BSD/macOS)

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of doing this, but the simplest is using `awk`:

```
function cat_or_fail () { awk '1;END{exit !NR}' "$@"; }
```

Here, `awk` returns a non-zero status if not a single line is read.

Alternatively, a tool available in the `moreutils` package. The command `ifne` allows one to execute a command, depending if `/dev/stdin` is empty or not:

- **`ifne command`:** run `command` if the standard input is not empty
- **`ifne -n command`:** run `command` if the standard input is empty. If the standard input is not empty, it sends standard input to standard output.

The latter is essentially what the OP expects. The function `cat_or_fail` would look like

```
function cat_or_fail () { ifne -n false; }
```

Which, if the OP wants to have a similar behaviour as `cat`, you could write it as:

```
function cat_or_fail () { cat -- "${@}" | ifne -n false; }
```

The latter can take files as arguments as well as read input from pipes similar to `cat`.

If you want to expand this to `command_or_fail`, where `command` is executed using standard input, or fail. You have to work a bit differently.

The return status of `ifne` is unaffected by the content of the standard input (empty or not). So you can not use it in an and-or sequence list (`foo && bar || baz`).

In order to create the requested behaviour, you need to use the `pipefail` option

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ function command_or_fail() { ifne -n false | ifne "$@"; }
$ echo foo | command_or_fail cat -n
1 foo
$ echo $?
0
$ </dev/null | command_or_fail cat -n
$ echo $?
1
```